# VS Code is forcing to run go mod tidy

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Error loading workspace: err: exit status 1: stderr: go: updates to go.mod needed, disabled by -mod=readonly; to update it: go mod tidy : packages.Load error

go mod tidy upgrades my package version which is breaking my code base and I don't want to update/modify my mod file because it's working in our Prod.

Is there any option to disable this in VS code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN6e0.png)

Comment: `go mod tidy` should not break your builds - it merely removes dead/unused dependencies. If it does error, then your `go.mod`  needs fixing.

Comment: check if there is correct versioning in go.mod ,i don't think go mod tidy will do any upgrade task, ` go get -u` is the command to upgrade

Comment: Is there any way to prevent version update of some module. 
for example
k8s.io/api v0.17.6
k8s.io/apimachinery v0.17.6

is getting update to
k8s.io/api v0.25.0
 k8s.io/apimachinery v0.25.0
which has breaking changes.

Comment: try removing the package then use the `go get`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.